# Array inside javascript property

Tags: javascript

```
function initialise() {
    doubleCount = 0;
    playerturn = 1;
    hotelrating = 0;
    flipped = 0;
    //setRent();
    //createPlayers(); 
    //createPositions();
    //createCards(); 
    //createSets();
    //drawBoard();
    //starplugin();
    //setPrices();
}

function playgame() {
    setPrices();
    clearContent();
    rollDice(); //two dice rolls
    drawDice(); //displays the dice
    setPosition(); //update player position 
    movePiece();
    checkForSale();
    checkDouble();
}

function starplugin() {
    $('#star').raty({
        path: 'lib/img/',
        cancel: true,
        cancelHint: 'remove my rating!',
        cancelPlace: 'right'
    });
    $("#star > img").click(function () {
        hotelrating = $(this).attr("alt");
    });
}

function clearContent() {
    if (flipped === 1) {
        //$(".cards").flippyReverse();
        $(".cards").flippy({
            color_target: "#F8F8F8",
            duration: "500"
        });
        flipped = 0;
    }
    $("#drawncardtitle").text("");
    $("#drawncard").text("");
    $("#buildsets1").hide();
    $("#buildsets2").hide();
    $('.buildsets').find('option').remove();
}

function canBuild() {
    var set = ["brown", "blue", "pink", "orange", "red", "yellow", "green", "navy"];
    var buildablesets = [
        [""],
        [""],
        [""]
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        if (doesOwnSet('player' + playerturn, set[i])) {
            buildablesets[playerturn].push(set[i]);
        }
    }
    buildablesetsx = buildablesets[playerturn];
    if (buildablesetsx.length > 1) {
        $(".buildmenu").toggle();
        $("#buildsets" + playerturn).show();
        buildsets = $("#buildsets" + playerturn);
        for (k = 1; k < buildablesets[playerturn].length; k++) {
            buildsets.append("<option value='" + buildablesetsx[k] + "'>" + buildablesetsx[k] + "</option>");
        }
    } else {
        $(".buildmenu").hide();
    }
}

function build() {
    var setname = $('#buildsets' + playerturn).find(":selected").text();
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var currentRating = sets[setname].rating;
    var ratingToAdd = hotelrating - currentRating;
    var cost = sets[setname].cost * ratingToAdd;
    if (hotelrating < currentRating) {
        alert("Sorry mate, you can't downgrade");
    }
    if (cost > balance) {
        alert("Sorry mate, you can't afford that!");
    } else {
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - cost;
        sets[setname].rating = hotelrating;

    }
    $(".buildmenu").hide();
}

function doesOwnSet(player, type) {
    return Object.keys(positions)
        .map(function (key) {
            return positions[key];
        })
        .filter(function (pos) {
            return pos.type === type;
        })
        .every(function (pos) {
            return pos.owner === player;
        });
}

function rollDice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    dice1 = x;
    dice2 = y;
    dicetotal = dice1 + dice2;
}

function drawDice() {
    $('.dice1').css('background-image', 'url(img/dice/' + dice1 + '.png)');
    $('.dice2').css('background-image', 'url(img/dice/' + dice2 + '.png)');
}

function drawBoard() {
    var set = ["brown", "blue", "pink", "orange", "red", "yellow", "green", "navy"];
    for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        var setcolor = sets[set[i]].color;
        if (set[i] == "yellow") {
            $('.yellow').css('color', 'black');
        }
        $('.' + set[i]).css('background', setcolor);
    }
}

function setPosition() {

    players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = players['player' + playerturn].startpos + dicetotal;
    players['player' + playerturn].prevpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos - dicetotal;
    currentposition = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;

    if (currentposition >= 40) {

        var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;

        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + 200;
        $("#debug2").text("+ $200");

        if (currentposition > 40) {

            players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = currentposition - 40;

        }

    }

    if (currentposition == 30) {

        players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = 10;

    }

    players['player' + playerturn].startpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
    title = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].title;
}

function movePiece() {

    var x = "#piece" + playerturn + "pos" + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
    var y = "#piece" + playerturn + "pos" + players['player' + playerturn].prevpos;
    $(x).slideToggle();
    $(y).slideToggle();

}

function checkForSale() {

    var forsale = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].forsale;

    if (forsale == "y") {
        checkOwner();
    } else {
        checkType();
    }

}

function checkOwner() {

    var owner = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].owner;

    if (owner == "none") {
        assignOwner();
    } else {
        payRent();
    }

}

function payRent() {

    var currentpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var type = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].type;


    if (type == "utility") {
        var rent = 4 * dicetotal;
    } else {
        var rent = positions['position' + currentpos].rent;
    }

    players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - rent;

}

function assignOwner() {
    var price = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].price;
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var title = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].title;

    players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - price;
    positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].owner = "player" + playerturn;
    //positions['position'+players['player'+playerturn].currentpos].price = positions['position'+players['player'+playerturn].currentpos].rent;
    $("#owns" + playerturn).append(title + '</br>');
}

function checkType() {
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var type = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].type;
    if (type == "tax") {
        var tax = positions['position' + players['player' + playerturn].currentpos].tax;
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - tax;
        $("#debug2").text("- $" + tax);
    } else {

        if (type == "chance") {
            chanceCard();
        } else if (type == "chest") {
            chestCard();
        }
    }

}

function chanceCard() {
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((16 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var title = chancecards['chance' + x].title;
    var type = chancecards['chance' + x].type;
    var bill = chancecards['chance' + x].bill;
    var bonus = chancecards['chance' + x].bonus;
    if (type == "bill") {
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - bill;
        $("#debug2").text("- $" + bill);
    } else if (type == "bonus") {
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + bonus;
        $("#debug2").text("+ $" + bonus);
    } else if (type == "move") {
        var newposition = chancecards['chance' + x].newposition;
        var currentposition = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
        if (newposition == 40) { //this if the player has to "advance to go"
            advanceToGo();
        } else if (newposition < currentposition) { //if the new position is less than the current one it means the player has to go past go
            players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + 200;
            $("#debug2").text("+ $200");
        }
        players['player' + playerturn].prevpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
        players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = newposition;
        players['player' + playerturn].startpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;

        movePiece();
        checkForSale();
    } else if (title == "Go back 3 spaces") {
        players['player' + playerturn].prevpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
        players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos - 3;
        players['player' + playerturn].startpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;

        movePiece();
        checkForSale();

    }
    $(".cards").css('display', 'block');
    $(".cards").flippy({
        color_target: "#F8F8F8",
        duration: "500",
        verso: '<span id="cardtitle">Chance</span><span id="cardinfo"> ' + title + '</span>'
    });
    flipped = 1;
}

function chestCard() {
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((14 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var title = chestcards['chest' + x].title;
    var chesttype = chestcards['chest' + x].type;
    var bill = chestcards['chest' + x].bill;
    var bonus = chestcards['chest' + x].bonus;

    if (chesttype == "bill") {
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance - bill;
        $("#debug2").text("- $" + bill);
    } else if (chesttype == "bonus") {
        players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + bonus;
        $("#debug2").text("+ $" + bonus);
    } else if (chesttype == "move") {
        var newposition = chestcards['chest' + x].newposition;
        var currentposition = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
        if (newposition == 40) { //this if the player has to "advance to go"
            advanceToGo();
        } else if (newposition < currentposition) { //if the new position is less than the current one it means the player has to go past go
            players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + 200;
            $("#debug2").text("+ $200");
        }
        players['player' + playerturn].prevpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
        players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = newposition;
        players['player' + playerturn].startpos = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;

        movePiece();
        checkForSale();

    }
    //$("#cardtitle").text("Community Chest");
    //$("#cardinfo").text(title);
    $(".cards").css('display', 'block');
    $(".cards").flippy({
        color_target: "#F8F8F8",
        duration: "500",
        verso: '<span id="cardtitle">Community Chest</span><span id="cardinfo"> ' + title + '</span>'
    });
    flipped = 1;
}

function advanceToGo() {
    var balance = players['player' + playerturn].balance;
    players['player' + playerturn].balance = balance + 200;
    $("#debug2").text("+ $200");
}

function checkDouble() {
    if (dice1 == dice2) {
        doubleCount++;
        if (doubleCount == 3) {
            var currentpossition = players['player' + playerturn].currentpos;
            players['player' + playerturn].currentpos = 10;
            changeTurn();
        }
    } else {
        changeTurn();
        doubleCount = 0;
    }
}

function changeTurn() {

    if (playerturn == 1) {
        playerturn = 2;
        $("#roll1").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#roll2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".buildmenu").hide();
        canBuild();
    } else {
        playerturn = 1;
        $("#roll2").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#roll1").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".buildmenu").hide();
        canBuild();
    }

}

function createPlayers() {
    players = {
        player1: {
            currentpos: 0,
            prevpos: 0,
            startpos: 0,
            balance: 1500
        },
        player2: {
            currentpos: 0,
            prevpos: 0,
            startpos: 0,
            balance: 1500
        }
    };
}

function createPositions() {
    positions = {
        position1: {
            title: "Cairo",
            type: "brown",
            owner: "player1",
            price: 60,
            rent: [2, 10, 30, 90, 160, 250],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position3: {
            title: "Vienna",
            type: "brown",
            owner: "player1",
            price: 60,
            rent: [2, 20, 60, 180, 320, 450],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position5: {
            title: "Schiphol",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position6: {
            title: "Brussels",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 100,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position8: {
            title: "Oslo",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 100,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position9: {
            title: "Zurich",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 120,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position11: {
            title: "Amsterdam",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 140,
            rent: [10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position13: {
            title: "Bangkok",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 140,
            rent: [10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position14: {
            title: "Istanbul",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 160,
            rent: [12, 60, 180, 500, 700, 900],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position15: {
            title: "Charles de Gaulle",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position16: {
            title: "Hong Kong",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 180,
            rent: [14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position18: {
            title: "Madrid",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 180,
            rent: [14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position19: {
            title: "Sydney",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: [16, 80, 220, 600, 800, 100],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position21: {
            title: "Toronto",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 220,
            rent: [18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position23: {
            title: "Mumbai",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 220,
            rent: [18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position24: {
            title: "Rome",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [20, 100, 300, 750, 925, 1100],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position25: {
            title: "Heathrow",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position26: {
            title: "Rio",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position27: {
            title: "Tokyo",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position29: {
            title: "Paris",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 280,
            rent: [24, 120, 360, 850, 1025, 1200],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position31: {
            title: "Berlin",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 300,
            rent: [26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position32: {
            title: "Bejing",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 300,
            rent: [26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position34: {
            title: "Moscow",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 320,
            rent: [28, 150, 450, 1000, 1200, 1400],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position35: {
            title: "John F Kennedy",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position37: {
            title: "New York",
            type: "navy",
            owner: "player2",
            price: 350,
            rent: [35, 175, 500, 1100, 1300, 1500],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position39: {
            title: "London",
            type: "navy",
            owner: "player2",
            price: 400,
            rent: [50, 200, 600, 1400, 1700, 2000],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position12: {
            title: "Electro",
            type: "utility",
            owner: "none",
            price: 150,
            rent: 10,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position28: {
            title: "Nuclear",
            type: "utility",
            owner: "none",
            price: 150,
            rent: 10,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position2: {
            title: "Community Chest",
            type: "chest"
        },
        position17: {
            title: "Community Chest",
            type: "chest"
        },
        position33: {
            title: "Community Chest",
            type: "chest"
        },
        position7: {
            title: "Chance",
            type: "chance"
        },
        position22: {
            title: "Chance",
            type: "chance"
        },
        position36: {
            title: "Chance",
            type: "chance"
        },
        position10: {
            title: "Jailhouse",
            type: "jail"
        },
        position20: {
            title: "Coffee House",
            type: "coffee"
        },
        position30: {
            title: "Go to Jail",
            type: "jail"
        },
        position40: {
            title: "Go",
            type: "home"
        },
        position4: {
            title: "Income Tax",
            type: "tax",
            tax: 200
        },
        position38: {
            title: "Super Tax",
            type: "tax",
            tax: 100
        }
    };
}

function createCards() {
    chancecards = {
        chance1: {
            title: "Advance to go",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 40
        },
        chance2: {
            title: "Advance to London",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 39
        },
        chance4: {
            title: "Your ass is going to jail",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 10
        },
        chance9: {
            title: "Advance to Rome",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 24
        },
        chance10: {
            title: "Advance to Charles de Gaulle",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 15
        },
        chance11: {
            title: "Advance to Amsterdam",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 11
        },
        chance6: {
            title: "Go back 3 spaces",
            type: "movex",
            newposition: -3
        },
        chance14: {
            title: "No drink and driving mate1",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 20
        },
        chance15: {
            title: "Get out of Jail free card",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        },
        chance7: {
            title: "Pay school fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        },
        chance12: {
            title: "Speeding fine",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        },
        chance5: {
            title: "Bank pays you dividend",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 40
        },
        chance13: {
            title: "You have won the competition",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        },
        chance16: {
            title: "Your building loan matures",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        },
        chance3: {
            title: "You are assessed for street repairs $40 per house $115 per hotel",
            type: "billx"
        },
        chance8: {
            title: "House repairs $25 per house $100 per hotel",
            type: "billx"
        }
    };
    chestcards = {
        chest1: {
            title: "Advance to go",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 40,
            bonus: 200
        },
        chest2: {
            title: "Advance to Cairo",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 1
        },
        chest3: {
            title: "Go to Jail",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 10
        },
        chest4: {
            title: "Pay hospital fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 100
        },
        chest5: {
            title: "Pay doctor fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 50
        },
        chest6: {
            title: "Pay insurance premium",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 50
        },
        chest7: {
            title: "Bank error. Collect $200",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        },
        chest8: {
            title: "Annuity matures. Collect $100",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 100
        },
        chest9: {
            title: "You inherit $100",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 100
        },
        chest10: {
            title: "From sale of stock you get $50",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 50
        },
        chest11: {
            title: "Preference shares: $25",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 25
        },
        chest12: {
            title: "You have won second prize in a beauty contest. Collect $10.",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        },
        chest13: {
            title: "It is your birthday. Collect $10.",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        },
        chest14: {
            title: "You win the lottery. Collect $10",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        }
    };
}

function createSets() {
    sets = {
        brown: {
            cost: 100,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#996600"
        },
        blue: {
            cost: 150,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#99CCFF"
        },
        pink: {
            cost: 300,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#FF0066"
        },
        orange: {
            cost: 300,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#FF6600"
        },
        red: {
            cost: 450,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#CC0000"
        },
        yellow: {
            cost: 450,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#FFFF00"
        },
        green: {
            cost: 600,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#006600"
        },
        navy: {
            cost: 400,
            rating: 0,
            color: "#003399"
        }
    };
}
```

What is wrong with my code? In the console log i get the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ ". It is something to do with the `rent` property? I am sorry if the question was not clear, didn't know how to ask it.

Comment: Should the last line be alert(positions["position1"] with position1 in quotes?

Comment: Do you have a variable `position1` or is it supposed to be a string? `alert(positions["position1"].rent[0]);`

Comment: Yes I forgot the speechmarks.

Comment: If you don't invoke the function, why would the object exist?

Comment: or you can the . property

Comment: It's weird that you get a syntax error though. Your syntax looks fine to me. Could the error be from another part of your code?

Comment: @ niels because i only posted the relevant code.

Comment: Since there's no SyntaxError in the code you posted, I'd say you *didn't* post the relevant code.

Comment: @cookiemonster it seems you are right. I assumed the error was with my `rent` property. Sorry.

Comment: Guys I have updated my question to include the full code now. I have commented out some functions to find which one;s are causing the error.

Comment: I ran your updated code. Still no SyntaxError there. Aren't you getting a file name and line number with the error?

Comment: @cookiemonster i have disabled all my functions bar one to print out `alert("i am working");` . Chrome browser still gives me an error but now the error says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL control.js:501
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialise is not defined (index):12
onload"

Comment: So is the code you posted from the `control.js` file?

Comment: @cookiemonster right i googled it and all I had to do was remove some lines at the end of the code. the code works now :S Oops I also forgot that stackoverflow limits my code to 3000. so it was not the full code!!! Im sorry again. Amateur!

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(positions['position1'].rent[0])
```

Put quotation marks around the 'position1'.

I also recommend that when there is only one rent, as in position 25, you still have it in an array. So like: `rent : [25]`

Also, in the first line in the function, do this:

```
window.positions = { /* ... your positions ... */ }
```

Comment: Yes but wha about the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ " error? Why is `[` unexpected?

Comment: where can i check what line the error is on? I am using chrome browser console log

Comment: usually, the chrome browser console has a filename and line number on the right side of the line that the error pops up on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the positions, also you need to call the function:

```
createPositions()
alert(positions["position1"].rent[0]);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YRJCP/

Answer (score 0):

you have made various mistake to declare your javascript object.

First you have declared the javascript object inside a function but you did not return the javascript object when you are calling the function.

Either you can return the javascript object from the function or you can remove the fucntion and just declare the objects inside sript tag

please look my below changes. it shall work now.

```
var positions = {
        position1: {
            title: "Cairo",
            type: "brown",
            owner: "player1",
            price: 60,
            rent: [2, 10, 30, 90, 160, 250],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position3: {
            title: "Vienna",
            type: "brown",
            owner: "player1",
            price: 60,
            rent: [2, 20, 60, 180, 320, 450],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position5: {
            title: "Schiphol",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position6: {
            title: "Brussels",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 100,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position8: {
            title: "Oslo",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 100,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position9: {
            title: "Zurich",
            type: "blue",
            owner: "none",
            price: 120,
            rent: [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position11: {
            title: "Amsterdam",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 140,
            rent: [10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position13: {
            title: "Bangkok",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 140,
            rent: [10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position14: {
            title: "Istanbul",
            type: "pink",
            owner: "none",
            price: 160,
            rent: [12, 60, 180, 500, 700, 900],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position15: {
            title: "Charles de Gaulle",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position16: {
            title: "Hong Kong",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 180,
            rent: [14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position18: {
            title: "Madrid",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 180,
            rent: [14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position19: {
            title: "Sydney",
            type: "orange",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: [16, 80, 220, 600, 800, 100],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position21: {
            title: "Toronto",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 220,
            rent: [18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position23: {
            title: "Mumbai",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 220,
            rent: [18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position24: {
            title: "Rome",
            type: "red",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [20, 100, 300, 750, 925, 1100],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position25: {
            title: "Heathrow",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position26: {
            title: "Rio",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position27: {
            title: "Tokyo",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 240,
            rent: [22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position29: {
            title: "Paris",
            type: "yellow",
            owner: "none",
            price: 280,
            rent: [24, 120, 360, 850, 1025, 1200],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position31: {
            title: "Berlin",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 300,
            rent: [26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position32: {
            title: "Bejing",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 300,
            rent: [26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position34: {
            title: "Moscow",
            type: "green",
            owner: "none",
            price: 320,
            rent: [28, 150, 450, 1000, 1200, 1400],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position35: {
            title: "John F Kennedy",
            type: "airport",
            owner: "none",
            price: 200,
            rent: 25,
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position37: {
            title: "New York",
            type: "navy",
            owner: "player2",
            price: 350,
            rent: [35, 175, 500, 1100, 1300, 1500],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },
        position39: {
            title: "London",
            type: "navy",
            owner: "player2",
            price: 400,
            rent: [50, 200, 600, 1400, 1700, 2000],
            rating: 0,
            forsale: "y"
        },

        position38: {
            title: "Super Tax",
            type: "tax",
            tax: 100
        }
    };
```

second you are accessing the object in a wrong way

> alert(positions.position1.rent[0]); //this should print 2

Comment: The variable isn't declared in the function. There's no `var` before it, so it's finds the outer variable with the same name, or creates a global variable.